# Video editing, how to make blur value a function of the time?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, drivers, graph-editor, timeline

My goal is to make the blur filter value, size X for instance, changing while the movie plays. 
I want the blur going up and down in time like a sinus function, for instance **`size_X = 1 + sin(time)`**.

So, I right clicked onto the size X value of in the blur filter of the video sequence editor and added a driver. 
Then, I went into the graph editor under drivers.

But from this point on, I do not know what to do, in order to make the time of the video clip the variable of the driver.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the cyclic function in the F-fcurve editor? Make 3 keyframes, 0,1,0 then extrapolate modifier cyclic.

[image: Cyclic blur]

Then you can spread them apart with scale S-key, constrain horizontal with X key

Answer (score 1):

Can use the new use self feature of drivers. Here I'm using the text editor to edit a driver method.  The strip is passed to this function, as is the current frame of the scene (the name frame is known to the driver namespace).

Below is a very simple example.  You may wish to investigate using other properties of the [strip](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_4/bpy.types.Sequence.html#module-bpy.types), for example `self.frame_start` is the frame on which the strip starts, `self.frame_duration` is its length etc.

You will need to run the script again after making edits.

```
import bpy
from math import sin

def blurdriver(strip, frame):
    # strip the blur strip
    # frame scene.frame_current
    # strip_frame_start = strip.frame_start

    #print(strip, frame)
    return 1 + sin(frame)


# register to the driver namespace

bpy.app.driver_namespace["bd"] = blurdriver
```

Run this script and the method "bd" will be available to drivers. As shown below, where self is the strip itself, and frame is the current frame of the scene.

[image]

If you want the script to auto run when blender file starts, give it a .py extension in name, and click the register button.
[image]